# A convex geometry definition

Tags: notation, convex-geometry

I found this def in my textbook:
Let A be a subset of a Euclidean vector space X. Then

$$A^* = \{y \in X: (x|y) =\lt 1, \;\;\forall x \in A\}$$
 is called to be an "extreme set" of A. (I'm not sure if I translate this right).
Can you explain me what is (x|y)? Can't find it anywhere on Google. Thanks!

Comment: My guess would be that it is the scalar product of $x$ and $y$ (as you are in a Euclidean vector space).

Comment: Eike, you are right! I was asking my teacher the other day and he said so. He also added that he used other notation than this while teaching us, that's why I got so confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of [extreme set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExtremeSet.html) at MathWorld, I would guess it means that **on the line between $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$**:

$$(1-t)\mathbf x + t\mathbf y \in A$$

then $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not the case. My fault, because of my limit English, I can't give the exact translation. I will try to put this def in better words.

Comment: @user302333 what is the word in your local language?